# Can't clear the cache of PSPDFDocument

Tags: ios, pdf, cache-control, pspdfkit

I'm having problems with clearing the cache of `PSPDFDocument` before and after deleting the PDF file.

here's what I do:

```
// ...
PSPDFDocument *document = [PSPDFDocument PDFDocumentWithUrl:(pdfURL)];
[document clearCacheForced:YES];

[mManagedObjectContext deleteObject:mPdfDocument];
// ...
```

when I try to clear entire cache for all PDFs, it works:

```
// ...
[[PSPDFCache sharedPSPDFCache] clearCache];
// ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the method name is a bit misleading, clearCacheForced on PSPDFDocument just releases some internal cache like the document page count, coordinates, annotation positions - not image content that is cached to disk by PSPDFCache. You need to call

```
- (void)removeCacheForDocument:(PSPDFDocument *)aDocument deleteDocument:(BOOL)deleteMagazine
```

in PSPDFCache to remove the cached images.

Also see the API documentation:
http://pspdfkit.com/documentation/Classes/PSPDFCache.html#//api/name/removeCacheForDocument:deleteDocument:

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've sent you an email with couple of questions.

Answer (score 0):

For PSPDFKit 4.1.0 + the [PSPDFCache sharedPSPDFCache] is deprecated, Please use this :

```
[[PSPDFKit sharedInstance].cache removeCacheForDocument:self.document deleteDocument:YES error:&error];
```